# setTimeout not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I'm trying set a timeout on a fading element so it has a little cushion before it fades in/out again. For some reason, my setTimeout function doesn't appear to be working. I've had this trouble before and i'd really like to know why.

This is what i'm using currently:

```
var button_timer;
    if (fade_in_but_hover != "none" && fade_out_but_hover != "none") {
        $(".first-level-items > .li").hover(function() {
            clearTimeout(button_timer);
            $(this).find("a").first().animate({ color: font_color_hover }, fade_in_but_hover);
        }).mouseleave(function() {
            button_timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).find("a").first().animate({ color: font_color }, fade_out_but_hover);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to scope `this`

```
  }).mouseleave(function () {
      var $this = $(this);//here
      setTimeout(function () {
          //use $this here
          $this.find("a").first().animate({
              color: font_color
          }, fade_out_but_hover);
      }, 1000);
  });
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be $this = $(this) if you want to use jQuery methods on it?

Comment: @Mathias Thanks, i always forget that :)